# Kill a Process where I Have only Part of the Process Name

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have to kill a process (an exe file) that does not have a distinctive name. All I know are the first two chars of its name for eg "3D".

How do I find the process name and kill it.

Here's my code where I check that the process is running but then what? I tried using the wildcard but it does not work.

### Option 1:

```
'-- get a collection of processes running
Dim nameProcess() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
    Debug.WriteLine(p.ProcessName)
    Next
    ' this is the process check function
    threeD = 3D 'I have declared this as string before in the code
    If IsProcessRunning(threeD) = True Then
        MsgBox("3D Found")
    End If
```

### Option 2:

```
    Dim proc() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("3D*")
    For Each temp As Process In proc
    temp.Kill()
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to come up with a working solution, Here it is:

```
    Dim nameProcess() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
    For i = 0 To nameProcess.Length - 1
        If nameProcess(i).ProcessName.StartsWith("3D") Then
            Dim exeName As String = nameProcess(i).ProcessName
            Dim proc() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(exeName)
            For Each temp As Process In proc
                temp.Kill()
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the process with `Process.Kill()`.

HOWEVER there is more than a chance that some other process can start with those letters, so you will need to do a lot more checks I would say before resorting to such an action.

Also you might want to wrap accessing the process in a `Try/Catch` because some processes, especially system ones, will throw an `AccessDeniedException` or worse when you try and interrogate them.

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process.GetProcesses() to get a list of the running processes. Then iterate through them and decide if there is a best match. (For example you may know it starts with "3D" and has exactly N characters in its name, or more than N etc.) Then you can try to kill the process as described in previous answer.

Other process properties (such as priority related properties, StartInfo, etc. ) may also be known and limit down your search results. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for a full list of properties.

Comment: THe thing is how to go through the array list - I tired this too but it does not work: Dim proc() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("3D*")
        For Each temp As Process In proc
        temp.Kill()
        Next

Comment: You probably have to use exact name for Process.GetProcessesByName (3D* will not work). Try this instead:
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
    If p.ProcessName.StartsWith("3D") Then
       p.Kill()
    End If
Next